# Style issues with meterial view pager library

Tags: android, styles, themes, android-appcompat

hi i just import meterial view pager library but it shows error in Style resource , i have used appcompact 7 ,

hear is the style code-

```
    <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
   <style name="MVP_AppBaseTheme"         
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  </style>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="MVP_AppTheme" parent="MVP_AppBaseTheme">

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/MVP_DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="19">true</item>

    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

    <!-- Toolbar Theme / Apply white arrow -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/MVP_AppTheme.ActionBarTheme</item>

    <!-- Material Theme -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color</item>

    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">@color/statusBarColor</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">@color/navigationBarColor</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:targetApi="21">true</item>

</style>

<style name="MVP_AppTheme.ActionBarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <!-- White arrow -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="MVP_DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@color/drawerArrowColor</item>
</style>
```

```
  end the error in second line
      <style name="MVP_AppBaseTheme"         
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

error is 
      ror: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'.
    please help if u can thanks in advance

Comment: Adding support library will solve the issue

Comment: i have allready add appcompact 7 library in my project

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error

You can try to use gms version 7.5

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.+'
    . . . 
}
```

Comment: i have worked with eclipse now i move in android studio with gradel its work fine thanks for your reply